# not simply ... but ... = not only ... but ...?

Tags: usage

Is the 3rd sentence in the passage paraphrased as the following sentence?

*We decide how much to eat ***not only*** as a function of how much food we actually consume, ***but*** by a comparison to its alternatives.*

I mean, does the sentence mean, '*We decide how much to eat by a comparison to its alternatives ***as well as*** as a function of how much food we actually consume.*'?

> Relativity works as a general mechanism for the mind, in many ways and
> across many different areas of life. For example, Brian Wansink,
> author of Mindless Eating, showed that it can also affect our
> waistlines. We decide how much to eat ***not simply*** as a function
> of how much food we actually consume, ***but*** by a comparison to its
> alternatives. Say we have to choose between three burgers on a menu,
> at 8, 10, and 12 ounces. We are likely to pick the 10­ounce burger and
> be perfectly satisfied at the end of the meal. But if our options are
> instead 10, 12, and 14 ounces, we are likely again to choose the
> middle one, and again feel equally happy and satisfied with the
> 12­ounce burger at the end of the meal, even though we ate more, which
> we did not need in order to get our daily nourishment or in order to
> feel full.

[Small Change: Money Mishaps and How to Avoid Them](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=xwouDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&dq=We%20decide%20how%20much%20to%20eat%20not%20simply%20as%20a%20function%20of%20how%20much%20food%20we%20actually%20consume,%20but%20by%20a%20comparison%20to%20its%20alternatives.%20Say%20we%20have%20to%20choose%20between%20three%20burgers%20on%20a%20menu,%20at%208,%2010,%20and%2012%20ounces.&source=bl&ots=KDDY1_M7lL&sig=ACfU3U2vh-W8CY6GQ_Xf5LqRK4wwFfwreg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHoLfO4av5AhWiGaYKHam6C0oQ6AF6BQjsARAD#v=onepage&q=We%20decide%20how%20much%20to%20eat%20not%20simply%20as%20a%20function%20of%20how%20much%20food%20we%20actually%20consume%2C%20but%20by%20a%20comparison%20to%20its%20alternatives.%20Say%20we%20have%20to%20choose%20between%20three%20burgers%20on%20a%20menu%2C%20at%208%2C%2010%2C%20and%2012%20ounces.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is puzzling but from the subsequent illustration I think what the writer means is that:

**It is not only our need for food that affects how much we decide to eat, but also the options on the menu.**

(Other interpretations would be welcome!)